# MVC Model binding with lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have this model:

```
 public class ReservationViewModel
 {        
  public Flight InboundFlight { get; set; }
  public Flight OutboundFlight { get; set; }
 }

 //Flight
 public class Flight
 {
  public List<ISeat> Seats { get; set; }
 }

 //Seats
  public interface ISeat 
  {
    ECabin Cabin { get; }
    int NumberOfSeatsAvailable { get; }
    int SeatsChosen { get; set; }
    string PropertyName { get; }
 }
```

My HTML consist of the folliwing:

```
<select id="OutboundFlight__0__Seats_SeatsChosen" name="OutboundFlight.[0].Seats.SeatsChosen" class="valid"><option...
<select id="OutboundFlight__0__Seats_SeatsChosen" name="OutboundFlight.[1].Seats.SeatsChosen" class="valid"><option...
<select id="OutboundFlight__0__Seats_SeatsChosen" name="OutboundFlight.[2].Seats.SeatsChosen" class="valid"><option...
```

My Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ReservationViewModel model, FormCollection form)
    {            
        return View();
    }
```

Upon submit I try to bind back to the model but the Seats of each flight returns null...
Help will be appreciated

Comment: You controller action(s) would be useful, too

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML being generated is incorrect to get it to bind to a list - the field name has to match what what accessing the property from c# would look like:

This should work:

```
name="OutboundFlight.Seats[0].SeatsChosen"
```

Comment: Now I get "Cannot create an instance of an interface" ..how to I solve this one?

Comment: Don't bind to an interface.  The default modelbinder doesn't know how to create an ISeat.  The easy way is to just change it to a concrete class, the harder way is to create a custom model binder.